# Paypal setExpressCheckout nvp tax amount error

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am requesting a setExpressCheckout call from paypal and I'm receiving the error code 10413. It was working perfectly fine until I took the tax away from the item total and added &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT into the request. Here is the request url:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?
METHOD=setExpressCheckout&VERSION=87.0
&USER=XXXXXXXXXX
&PWD=XXXXXXXXXX
&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXXXX
&RETURNURL=XXXXXXXXXX
&CANCELURL=XXXXXXXXXX
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Hy+Guardian+Fly+Rug
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=HY-FLY
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Size%3A+4+ft+6%2C+Size%3A+4+ft+6%2C+Size%3A+4+ft+6%2C+Size%3A+4+ft+6
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=47.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=37.60
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=11.25
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=9.40
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=58.25
```

Comment: Looking at your `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_` variable, they equate to 58.25, yet the `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0` is for 47.00... This could be the cause?

Comment: Yes, Thats it! Thanks :)

Comment: I've stuck the above into an answer below ;) glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comments,

It seems your total amount is different to your item total amount.

i.e.

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=37.60
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=11.25
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=9.40
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=58.25
```

Shows 58.25

Yet

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=47.00
```

Shows 47.00

The price mismatch is likely to cause this problem ;)

Comment: Exactly. Similarly, on a recent integration, I was specifying tax on a per line item basis, which resulted in rounding errors since my application rounds sales taxes at the order level, not the line item level. A PayPal engineer informed me that this line item tax amount is never actually used anyways, so I don't see any reason to ever set it in an API request. Just have to make sure we're not included sales taxes in the ITEMAMTs. : )